# Copy pen drive data into android device using Android source code

Tags: android-studio

I want to transfer files from pen drive to Android device (with OTG cable) using android studio. Please suggest me.  Discover pen drive and copy pen drive data into Android device.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your work

Comment: I fallow this link.  pls tell me Am I going right way?http://mobilemerit.com/android-app-for-usb-host-with-source-code/

Answer (score 0):

If you have an OTG cable then you should be able to directly copy your data to your Android device. I don't see the need to use Android Studio here.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Android Studio i.e 3.0 stable build has a built in feature to browse connected android devices from inside the studio IDE. It is located on the bottom right panel and is called Device File Explorer. You might need read/write permissions to do so though.[image]